# What is the (0X0003) in socket creation?

Tags: python, sniffing

i m developing a program for packet sniffing in PYTHON but i am not getting what does the (0x0003)parameter means in 'ntohs' function in python..

```
s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW , socket.ntohs(0x0003))
```

Comment: seems like a hex code.

Answer (score 7):

In linux `socket.ntohs(0x0003)` tells capture everything including ethernet frames.
To capture TCP, UDP, or ICMP only, instead of `socket.ntohs(0x0003)` you will write `socket.IPPROTO_TCP`, `socket.IPPROTO_UDP` and `socket.IPPROTO_ICMP` respectively.

In windows, the socket can only capture IP and above and cannot capture ethernet. To do that you can use `pypcap` library in the windows.

Comment: I'm using `socket.ntohs(0x0003)` to capture UDP.  `socket.IPPROTO_UDP` isn't working for me.  Linux.  Python 3.6.8

Answer (score 2):

It is the protocol to use. From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket) -

> **socket.socket([family[, type[, proto]]])**
>
> Create a new socket using the given address family, socket type and protocol number. The address family should be AF_INET (the default), AF_INET6 or AF_UNIX. The socket type should be SOCK_STREAM (the default), SOCK_DGRAM or perhaps one of the other SOCK_ constants. The protocol number is usually zero and may be omitted in that case.

If protocol is ommitted it defaults to 0 , which causes the protocol to be taken based on the `family` (first argument).

For linux, You can find the list of protocol numbers in `/etc/protocols` . I believe when you give protocol as `0x0003` it is using GGP (Gateway-Gateway protocol) .

Comment: I am using same line in my program: s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW , socket.ntohs(0x0003)) and getting error that .. _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted .. what should I use instead of there parameters?

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter is the `protocol` and is normally left as 0, which is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=socket.socket#socket.socket).

The IANA list the [Assigned Internet Protocol Numbers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xml), '0x0003` is defined as:

`3  GGP  Gateway-to-Gateway`

The `ntohs()` function though is used to do an endian swap on the number if required (based on the architecture you are running on). For your example this could be `0x0300` or `768`, which does not make sense to me. Perhaps someone else knows of a special use case for which I am not aware.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [linux/if_ether_h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ead751507de86d90fa250431e9990a8b881f713c/include/uapi/linux/if_ether.h) you will aww

```
#define ETH_P_ALL   0x0003  /* Every packet (be careful!!!) */
```

so 0x0003 means capture all packets

Answer (score 0):

from the python official socket [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html)

`socket.ntohs(0x0003)` captures all the send & receive traffic from the network interface.